# Is the explanation for this disastrous declaration even correct?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, declaration

I just started a new job where I'm part of the only team working on C projects. So I presented this picture: [image]

which already decorated my desk on the old working place, where I just took the explanation as granted.

The idea of putting it next to our office's door case was well received. When I got asked, if I understand what this is doing and if I could explain it later this day, I agreed and prepared my self a little bit to explain it.

But I got stucked. Ignoring the additional hint which is semantically already wrong, I'm confused about the appearance of 2 empty argument-expression-list's.

Wouldn't that mean, `void (*(*f[])())()`is actually: `f`, identifying an array of unspecified size, of pointers to functions that return pointers to functions which return void?

Or am I just missing something since my C skills might have got a bit rusty?

Comment: That is also called [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: Yes, you are correct: https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28%2A%28%2Af%5B%5D%29%28%29%29%28%29

Comment: As for the empty parentheses for a function, in C++ it means no arguments, effectively a `void` argument. In C it's a very different matter, where it is a function with an unknown number of unspecified arguments, if used in a declaration. Or it means no arguments (i.e. a `void` argument) if used in a definition.

Comment: Also, arrays without a specific size is allowed in two places: When defining an array with *initialization* so the compiler can deduce the size; Or last in a `struct` where it becomes a [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). Other than that one must specify a size of the array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yep, thanks for the comment. I know that one, thats why I actually decided to take this picture as help for refreshing my knowledge, since this person seemed to understand something about it. But... well... his explanation in it self seems to ignore his own spiral, so ignoring his statement which obviously is wrong, I'm now even in doubt the first text is correct.

Comment: The text is actually wrong. `f` is an array of unspecified length (which can only be used in two places) which contains pointers to functions that takes an unspecified amount arguments of unspecified type. The functions returns not `void` but a pointer to a function taking an unspecified number or arguments of unspecified type, and those functions return `void`. So the text misses the return type of the function-pointers in the array.

Comment: Well you can stare at such code, with your mind going in spiral patterns, on the verge of insanity... or you can use typedef, as has already been discussed in millions of other posts. It boils down to: 1) if you write code like this, you are insane, 2) if you try to read & understand code like this, you'll get insane, and 3) the people who made this syntax possible were definitely insane.

Comment: Also this code won't even compile in any version of C, because VLA's cannot be empty. Therefore a very bad example. C is quite hard... the person who wrote that code had just not yet realized.

Comment: @Lundin: I have to disaggre, at least to your second post. I can aggree with point 1 and 2 of your first point and partial with your 3rd point, but your second comment is just wrong. note, this actually isn't the usage of an VLA. The standard specifies it as "array of unknown size". Look it up. Its fully legit. And while this is as the title states an desastrous example, this feature finds its usage. Also look Vlads answer for an example of valid code using this feature.

Comment: @Zaibis You can declare an array of incomplete type, but that is not meaningful unless part of a function parameter list, which isn't the case here. You would have to make a second declaration such as `void (* (*f[n])())();` later in the code. If you wish to declare a VLA of incomplete type you would write `type arr[*]`, which again only makes sense inside a function declaration. The example by Vlad does not use any incomplete type since he added an initializer list and removed the `;`, changing the meaning of the declaration.

Comment: That is, there is no such thing as "an array of unknown size" in the C language. There are only arrays of incomplete type, that cannot be used in meaningful ways until their type has been completed (or before they have been adjusted to pointers, as part of a parameter list).

Comment: @Lundin: Not disaggreing with that, but I also don't see why that should be contradicting with anything, I said. Note this whole phrase isn't about productive code, but about all the little questionable features of C. And there are such things as  "array of unknown size". I just copy pasted that exact wording from my iso/iec copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters in C such a function declaration like

```
void f();
```

means that the number and types of parameters are defined based on the function call.

From the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 14 An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters
>   of the function. An empty list in a function declarator that is part
>   of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no
>   parameters. **The empty list in a function declarator that is not part
>   of a definition of that function specifies that no information about
>   the number or types of the parameters is supplied**

So if the function does not have parameters it is better to write

```
void f( void );
```

Though it is not important nevertheless for clarity let's rewrite the declaration

```
void(*(*f[])( ))( )
```

like

```
void(*(*f[])( void ))( void )
```

This declaration declares an array of unspecified size (the size of the array is determinate from the number of initializers) of pointers to functions. The functions have no parameters and return pointers to functions that in turn have no parameters and have return type void.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func2(void)
{
    puts("Hello C");
}

void(*(func1)( void ))( void )
{
    return func2;
}

int main( void )
{
    void(*(*f[])( void ))( void) = { func1 };

    f[0]()();
}

void(*(*f[])())()
```

Its output is

```
Hello C
```

The declaration can be simplified by introducing a typedef.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func2(void)
{
    puts("Hello C");
}

typedef void(*FP)(void);

FP func1(void)
{
    return func2;
}

int main( void )
{
    FP ( *f[] )( void ) = { func1 };

    f[0]()();
}
```